# Bash script to install website

Tags: bash, mysql, database

First of all, excuse me if this is the wrong place to ask this question.

I made a Bash script which installs a DirectAdmin backup into Apache.
The steps are working but in the end I get a 500 error when opening the actual website.

Steps:
1. Unpack backup.tar.gz
2. remove unessecary files
3. Ask for database details en website name
4. Cat to admin.conf files
5. Create database and user
6. Create and cat to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/website.conf`
7. `a2ensite` and `service apache2 reload`
8. Create an entry in Windows hosts file

I have traced all the steps back and all seems to work but when I enter the URL I get a 500 error. 
Did all this without a script and everything works.

Can someone tell me where the error could come from?
Is there something different when doing all these steps with a bash script?

EDIT:
Here is the entire script used:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
tar -zxvf backup.tar.gz
sudo cp -R ./domains/*/public_html/* ./
sudo cp ./backup/*.sql ./
rm -rf ./backup ./domains
rm backup.tar.gz
sudo chmod 775 ./config.php
echo "ROOT_PWD?"
read -s root_pwd
echo "WEBSITENAME?"
read website
echo "DB_USERNAME?"
read usrname
echo "DB_PASSWORD?"
read db_pwd
echo "DB_DATABASE?"
read db
cat > ./config.php <<EOL
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.$website.nl/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://www.$website.nl/');

// HTTPS 
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://www.$website.nl/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://www.$website.nl/');

// DIR 
define('DIR_APPLICATION', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/admin/'); 
define('DIR_SYSTEM', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/system/'); 
define('DIR_IMAGE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/image/'); 
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/admin/language/'); 
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/admin/view/template/'); 
define('DIR_CONFIG', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/system/config/'); 
define('DIR_CACHE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/system/storage/cache/'); 
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/system/storage/download/'); 
define('DIR_LOGS', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/system/storage/logs/'); 
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/system/storage/modification/'); 
define('DIR_UPLOAD', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/system/storage/upload/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/catalog/');

// DB 
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli'); 
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost'); 
define('DB_USERNAME', '$usrname'); 
define('DB_PASSWORD', '$db_pwd'); 
define('DB_DATABASE', '$db'); 
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
EOL
chmod 444 ./config.php
chmod 755 ./admin/config.php
cat > ./admin/config.php <<EOL
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.$website.nl/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://www.$website.nl/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://www.$website.nl/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://www.$website.nl/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/admin/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/image/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/admin/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/admin/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/system/config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/system/storage/upload/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/catalog/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', '$usrname'); 
define('DB_PASSWORD', '$db_pwd'); 
define('DB_DATABASE', '$db');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
EOL
chmod 444 ./admin/config.php

mysql -u root -p$root_pwd -e "CREATE DATABASE $db"
mysql -u root -p$root_pwd -e "CREATE USER '$usrname'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$db_pwd';"
mysql -u root -p$root_pwd -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $db . * TO '$usrname'@'localhost';"
mysql -u $usrname -p$db_pwd $db < *.sql

touch /etc/apache2/sites-available/$website'.conf'
cat > /etc/apache2/sites-available/$website'.conf' <<EOL
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName $website.nl
    ServerAlias www.$website.nl
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/$website/

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
EOL
a2ensite $website'.conf'
service apache2 reload
```

When I made a backup from DirectAdmin from the website www.example.com and I used this website in my script everything went the way it supposed to but when entering the URL in a browser, I get the 500 error.

The Apache logs are empty.

Comment: We can't really tell since you haven't shown us your script; only what you think it does. You may be 100% right and it does do what you think it does, or you may be wrong and in fact it does something else. What URL do you enter? Where do you enter it? How do you enter it?  Please [edit] your question and show us the actual commands you use.

Comment: What does the Apache error log say?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but we still don't know where the error occurs. When you enter which URL? At which command does it fail? At which step? Also, does your root password contain special characters?

Comment: Let's say for example we use www.example.com. FIrst I download a backup from DirectAdmin. Then I copy the backup file and the script to the destination folder on my server. After thats done I execute my script which is asking me for the root password (this does include special characters) so it can create a database and user credentials. This still works and a database is created. Then the script is asking for a website name which is "example". After the script enters all nesaccery info I add a entry to my Windows hosts file. After entering www.example.com in the browser I get a 500 error

Comment: This is a PHP error. The problem may not lie with your installation script. Enable PHP logging of errors and see what PHP has to say.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information! I managed to fix it by removing the relative path in the config files :D

Comment: @PdC: (1) Please use accurate edit summaries.  You seem to be repeatedly using canned edit summaries that have no relation to the edit.  For example, here you said, “Minor grammar errors fixed and syntactic sugar added.” (which you have used verbatim on at least two other edits), but all you did was fix capitalization.  (You do also sometimes fix formatting.) (2) When you edit a post, please do your best to fix *all* the problems with it.  Yesterday I rejected one of your suggested edits because it made low-priority changes to capitalization and formatting, but left a spelling error untouched.

Comment: @G-Man, thanks for input. So essentially you are pointing out that I missed one spelling error and make low priority changes that increase readability. How detailed should the edit summaries be? I mean, the ones I already use are a sentence long. When it comes to minor edits (such as capitalization), should I write (for instance) : "Changed an i to I, removed two commas, and altered the sentence structure to follow the subject-verb-object form."?

Comment: (1) Actually, you’ve been overlooking a few errors. (2) Whether you are improving readability is debatable.  IMO, “bash” is fine as is, and changing it to “Bash” is not an improvement.  Changing “apache” → “Apache” is not much better. (3) I didn’t say “longer”, I said “accurate”.  If you change capitalization and formatting, say “Improved capitalization and formatting”.

Answer (score -1):

Oh, You need to use `ip_conntrack`, Do the following steps:

1. `modprobe ip_conntrack`
2. get list of variables of `sysctl` with `sysctl -a |grep -i conn`:
   output is ":

   ```
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_acct = 0
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_buckets = 65536
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_checksum = 1
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_count = 116
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_events = 1
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_expect_max = 1024
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_generic_timeout = 600
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_helper = 0
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_icmp_timeout = 30
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_log_invalid = 0
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 262144
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_be_liberal = 0
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_loose = 1
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_max_retrans = 3
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close = 10
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait = 60
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 432000
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait = 120
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_last_ack = 30
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_max_retrans = 300
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_recv = 60
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_sent = 120
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait = 120
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_unacknowledged = 300
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_timestamp = 0
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout = 30
   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout_stream = 180
   net.nf_conntrack_max = 262144
   ```
3. change `net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max`  varibale.
4. store in file.

Comment: Please could you explain why this would fix a 500 error?

Comment: This variable tell to kernel how many client can connect to server.No difference , www, squid, or any client.